# Size of android app

Tags: android, image

Most of the link on SO suggest to use same image with different sizes in `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xdpi`. But the problem is I have more than 15 images. If I do like they suggest i think its increase the size of my app. As each image is at least 50 kb. Is there is any other way to use so many images that support all screen sizes? And if i use each image with different sizes in `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xdpi`. Is this increase my app size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer, YES, it will increase your app's size if you prepare all `ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi` images.

In some special case, if your app have really large image for tablet, you can use [Multiple Apk Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).
This will let you create different apk which has limited image resource only target for limited devices.

Answer (score 3):

1. Unless you do not have hell lot of images in your app, it is okay to have app size increase, yes it good to design app to have less in size but keep in mind that, if its required its okay to have a app size maximum upto 50Megs~Read [Android Apps Break the 50MB Barrier](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html)
2. Another way to go with supporting images to have support for varied screens, go with Nine-patch images. A `NinePatchDrawable` graphic is a stretchable bitmap image, which Android will automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the View in which you have placed it as the background. Read [Nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

Comment: so thats a good thing , you hav so many ways, read them one by one, see whats suitable and best applicable for you and go with it

Comment: Is it possible to create app first and then decrease the size of apk?

Comment: no you cannot, altough apk file is internally zipped and compressed, but no provision after that

Comment: Can i use nine patch image as background on whole screen also?

Comment: @JohnR Yes you can, its totally upto you how well you design it and and where and how you use it

Comment: I'd like to highjack this conversation just to emphasise that for all practically purposes, you should provide multiple images per DIP bucket. It is only in special cases where you might want to consider leaving some or all of the DPI bucket resources out.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and provide more detail about what you're struggling to understand. We've all given you a lot of information regarding the subject. I'm giving you the general advice that you shouldn't worry about the application size and should instead generate the different images for each bucket size as this is what practically every other application does.

Answer (score 1):

You can go without downscaling all the the different sizes, but then you must be aware of the two major issues:

1. There is a performance penalty of Android having to downscale the images manually every time they are accessed. This is especially an issue on older/slower devices. This could cause your list views to stutter, increase load times and generally make things lag in the worst case. I'm not entirely certain, but you may also run into memory issues on devices with little RAM.
2. Automatic downscaling of some images will lead to a bad visual result. Especially with fine detail or in the case of logos, where everything should look as good as possible. In particular this is an issue the more the image is downscaled. So if you provide an XXHDPI image only, then it will likely not look good on MDPI or LDPI devices.

As long as these two points are less of an issue than the application size, then you can consider leaving it up to Android to downscale. Though in most cases you're looking at around 3 times more storage space required than if you didn't include them (keen in mind that they are smaller images, so they take up a lot less space. A 50kb xdpi image will have an equivalent mdpi images at 12.5kb because both width and height are halved).

Also note that if you must only provide one image, then it should be the highest resolution image available, otherwise the image will be upscaled which looks terrible on higher resolution screens.

Finally, worth noting is that the Android will compress the images in the APK, so the file size you see may not be the same as the amount of space it takes up in the APK.

For the sake of completeness, as @Akhil Jain mentioned. A great way to reduce your image space cost is through the use of 9 patches. Be sure to use them whenever appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

yes this will increase your `apk` size and the application size because `apk` is downloaded together with all images for all resolutions. If you want any images common for all screens, then you can create a `drawable folder` and place the image in it. So it will pick automatically. For more detail go through this link [Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Thats good you can give emphasis on the section **Alternative drawables** in that link.